# JavaScript Syntax checker in Java Swing GUI

Tags: java

I have made an application on java GUI in which the user will upload .js(java script file) and the program will tell the syntax errors in .js code. I have almost completed the code it is working fine but I am facing a little problem that the output is coming in my console window but i want the output in jtextfield. Can someone help me?

Here is my Java GUI code:

```
ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
     ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    try {
          jTextArea4.setText((String) engine.eval(new java.io.FileReader("E:\\yourfile.js"))); } 

    catch (ScriptException ex) 
    {
    Logger.getLogger(Menu.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null, ex);
    } 
      catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
     {
      Logger.getLogger(Menu.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null, ex);
    }

     catch (ScriptException ex)
      {
        Logger.getLogger(Menu.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);}

       catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
      {
        Logger.getLogger(Menu.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);}
```

Comment: Do you have any Exceptions, or does `eval` succeed ?

Comment: eval show error in console but i want that error in gui jtext

Comment: Shows what error in the console?

Comment: its done thank you but now i want to do it with php code how can i do this ?